# Creating a custom class in IOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an existing project that requires porting a Swift Mock to to Objective C which I haven't used before.  I have been trying to complete this so would value some help on the approach to take.  I have tried several tutorials but I seem to have xcode sharing errors.

**Error:**
Xcode doesn't seem to recognise the class in the VC
 `Property 'assetName' not found on object of type '__strong id'`

```
## Code to port to objective C

  struct Asset {
    let assetName: String
    let assetColour: String
    let assetValue: Int
    let AssetSource: String
  }
    struct ExternalAsset {
        let assetName: String
        let assetColour: String?
        let assetSupplier: String?
        let assetValue: Int?
        let assetMargin: Double?
    }
```

Here is the attempt I made from Objective C from following som older tutorials

**ExternalAsset.h**

```
@interface ExternalAsset:NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *assetName;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *assetColour;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *assetSupplier;
@end
```

**ExternalAsset.m**

```
#import "ExternalAsset.h"
@implementation ExternalAsset

@end
```

in my calling class - I have the following:

AssetCatalogue.h

```
    - (void)didPayforAsset:(ExternalAsset *)assetPaidFor // Error Message ( "Expected a Type")
    {
  NSMutableDictionary *paidItems = [@{
    "AssetName": assetPaidFor.assetName, 
// `Error:  Property 'AssetName' not found on object of type '__strong id'
  } mutableCopy];
    }


@end
```

Comment: Show the calling code. Your class declaration is correct.

Comment: Thanks - I added in the details.

Comment: @UKDataGeek - are you trying to re-write Swift code that uses `struct` as Objective-C classes? Or, are you trying to pass a Swift struct to Objective-C code?

Comment: @UKDataGeek What we'd like to see is whatever code actually generates the error. There must be someplace in your code where you create an instance of `ExternalAsset` and then try to access it's `assetName` property, right? That's the part you need to add here.

Comment: Did you import `ExternalAsset.h`?

Comment: From the error is obvious that the compiler does not recognize class `ExternalAsset` (considers the type to be just `id`). That means the compiler does not see the declaration. Make sure `ExternalAsset.h` is properly imported.

Comment: Thanks that worked - do you want to answer this question so I can say thanks - otherwise I can post answer